# excel find gap in dates

Tags: excel, date, range

I have a range of dates in the following format

`Hire   TERM    ReHire1 TERM2   ReHire2 TERM3   ReHire3 TERM4`

The problem is that some rows might be missing a date, say a row will have dates in all but 'term' (B2).  I can go in and use the filters to show blanks, but this becomes a nuisance when there are 15-20 date columns.  Is there a formula that will look at the whole range and return an error of sort where there are empty cells?

Below is a comma delimited sample data that you can import into excel to help illustrate.

```
Hire,TERM,ReHire,TERM,ReHire,TERM,ReHire,TERM
05/06/2002,12/09/2002,,05/12/2003,02/10/2004,03/29/2005,,
05/30/2000,05/24/2004,09/27/2004,11/27/2004,,08/31/2006,05/24/2007,
03/15/2004,02/01/2005,02/16/2005,06/13/2005,02/06/2006,03/13/2006,10/14/2007,01/06/2008
03/13/1998,08/28/1998,,11/20/2000,11/03/2002,07/23/2009,09/08/2009,11/21/2009
07/12/2007,05/01/2009,07/12/2007,05/01/2009,07/28/2011,,07/28/2011,
12/20/2004,11/11/2005,02/23/2009,11/25/2009,08/10/2010,08/24/2010,,
08/23/2001,08/11/2002,,11/22/2006,01/15/2007,,,
```

Additional details per feedback:

A `missing value` -or "gap" as I call it- would be if a row has dates under hire and rehire but no date on Term.

Comment: Do you want manual labor, or vba-automated solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either:

- **Split your data with Excel builtin solution** and choose to split on commas `,`

  - Select your data on Excel
  - Then click on "Data", "Text To Columns..."
  - Click on the "Delimited" radio button
  - Then click on the "Next" button, in "Delimeters" put a checkmark in "Comma"
  - Then click on the "Finish" button.
  - and then find the empty cells with a conditional formula
- **Use this kind of formula**

  `=IF(ISERR(FIND(",,",A1)),"Missing value","")`

  to check if there is any missing value

Comment: This wont flag gaps, if there is a row with one date (hire) all the others should be blank, `=IF(ISERR(FIND(",,",b1:AA1)),"Missing value","")` returns a `missing value` when there is no missing value. A `missing value` -or "gap" as I call it- would be if a row has a hire and rehire date but no date on Term

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to use conditional formatting on the cells.  In Excel 2010, highlight the data range, pick "home->conditional formatting->highlight cell rules->more rules".

Then pick "format only cells that contain" and change the drop down with "Cell Value" to "Blanks" and click the "Format..." button and set how you want it highlighted (Fill color to yellow for example).

Alternativley, you could add a formulae "countblank" either over the the entire range or a subrange (row for example) and it will specify the number of blank cells.  For example, you could in the final column add "=countblank(a2:h2)" and then filter the results for anything greater than 0.  This would show you all the rows with missing data and you could correct them as needed.

Comment: not sure if conditional formatting would work, if there is a row with only one date (hire) it would highlight all the other cells, when they should be empty.   The countblank will reduce the list, but not really flag those that have a gap in the date range.  It's not about looking for empty cells, but looking for a gap of any range (which in excel is represented by a blank cell)

Answer (score 0):

I have imported your data into Excel 2011 on a mac.
If I understand your question, all you want to do is to find the empty cells. Then you just press CMD-F or CTRL-F on windows to start a search. You just leave the search field empty. Excel will then show you the empty fields one by one.

Comment: what if there are 1000 rows to review? wont help reduce the review, that's my goal.